# Ajax to load page changing the url

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am writing the following code to load a part of the page:

```
function load(b)
{
var xmlHttp;
try
{   
    xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
catch (e)
{
    try
    {
        xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); 
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        try
        {
            xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch (e)
        {
            alert("No AJAX!?");
            return false;
        }
    }
}

xmlHttp.open("GET",b,true);
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
if( this.readyState == 4 )
{
    document.getElementById('main').innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
}
}

    xmlHttp.send(null); 
}
```

//And the HTML to call the code is:

```
<a href="#" onclick="load('reg.php')">Item 3.1.1</a>
```

It is having correct result. But in url it comes as : localhost/corpo/#

whereas I am expecting: localhost/corpo/reg.php

Comment: If you want to go to reg.php why bother with Ajax?

Comment: Sir, actually I don't want to load the complete page, rather I just want to load a <div> tag of the HTML to save the download of the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `<span>`

for example:

```
 <span onClick="load('reg.php');">hello</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hyperlink in `<a>` element points to '#', so everything is fine.

Before HTML5 you could only manipulate the hash portion of url from JavaScript, so your expectation was impossible to implement.

With arrival of HTML5 however it's feasible. Check this link: http://spoiledmilk.dk/blog/html5-changing-the-browser-url-without-refreshing-page or anything that goole says about for example "html5 url change"

Comment: Sir, I din't get that. Actually I am new to JavaScript and Ajax and knows very little of them. Most of the time it is a copy paste. so what code I should add to my existing code. or what change should I make to my existing code to attain what I am seeking for?